# Increment a value depending on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following problem...

I have a table `AccountingEntry` which currently has a primary key, which is the accounting `ID`. I also have a column which tells me which type of entry it is...

What I need to do is the following...

If the row is of a certain type (lets say `CreditCardPayment`, I need to increment the value of another column, lets say `CCId` by one... How can I accomplish this??

(Just a heads up, no table separation can be done)

This needs to be done in the INSERT statement....

Lets say in my Database I have..

ID   |   TYPE    |  ANOTHER ID
1    |   DEBIT   |     -
2    |   CREDIT  |     1
3    |   DEBIT   |     -
4    |   CREDIT  |     x -> This needs to be the last credit 'AnotherID' + 1

Comment: You want to UPDATE a row, SETting a value to a new one, WHERE a condition is met.  Not very difficult to convert to SQL, if you are even slightly familiar with it..?

Comment: I Need to do it in my INSERT... not in a different SQL...

Comment: INSERT creates a new record, it doesn't modify (increment) anything

Comment: I Know... One of the columns in the new record, needs to be +1 than the last record of the same type....

Comment: SELECT the existing value and INSERT the same value + 1, then?  What exactly is the question - are you struggling with a particular bit of SQL syntax?

Comment: Will this be an actual production application, and will it have more than one concurrent user?

Comment: I Updated my question..hope it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `UPDATE` with `WHERE` condition should do the work here:

```
UPDATE TableName SET CCId = CCId + 1 WHERE Type = 'CreditCardPayment'
```

*Update*

You can do it automatically after `INSERT` statement using trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoIncrement
ON TableName
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE
        TableName
    SET
        CCId = -- put your 'get last of that type + 1 here
    WHERE
        Type = 'CreditCardPayment' AND Id = inserted.Id
GO
```

`-- put your 'get last of that type + 1 here` can be something like:

```
SELECT TOP(1) AnotherID FROM TableName WHERE Type = 'CreditCardPayment' ORDER BY AnotherID DESC
```

Comment: Post your current INSERT statement then!

Comment: Updated my answer ... You should definitely read your question twice before asking

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run a one time instance, you can use the Row_Number() function.

```
select rowtype, accountingid, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by rowtype order by rowtype, accountingid)
```

This will get you an unique row number for each rowtype ordered by accountingid.  Then if you need this info in the database, you can run an update with the select or put the selected rows in a temp table and update that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the resulting Trigger... Works perfect for what I needed. After running a script to alter the data in my database that I had up to now, everytime a record is inserted, if it's of the type I needed, it will autoincrement the field InvoiceNumber.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IncrementInvoiceNumber 
       ON  AccountingEntry
       AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @insertedId INT;
        SELECT TOP(1) @insertedId = IdAccountingEntry FROM AccountingEntry ORDER BY IdAccountingEntry DESC;
        UPDATE AccountingEntry SET InvoiceNumber = ( SELECT TOP(1) InvoiceNumber FROM AccountingEntry
                                                     WHERE AccountEntryType = 'I'
                                                     ORDER BY InvoiceNumber DESC    
                                                    ) + 1
                               WHERE IdAccountingEntry = @insertedId;

    END
```